# Jest service API call response always executing catch block in angular

Tags: angular, jestjs, jasmin

I have a Jest test case where I am calling a method inside the angular component. That method has a service call. But somehow I am not able to mock the response object of service

app.component.ts

```
  someMethod() {
    try {
      this.appService.test().then((response) => {
        //I want JEST to execute some logic here after response
      }
    }
    catch (e) { 
      //JEST always going in this block while testing
    }
  }
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {appService} from "./appService";
import { appComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('appComponent', () => {
  let component: appComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<appComponent>;
  let MockappService : appService;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  class mockServiceClass {
    test(): any {
      return { data: {}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {}, config: {} }
    }
  }
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ appComponent ], 
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [{ provide: appService, useClass: mockServiceClass}],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, BrowserModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(appComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    MockappService = TestBed.inject(appService);
    // this fixture.detectChanges will kick off the ngOnInit
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  describe('On value change', () => {
    it('should validate the form', () => {
      component.someMethod();
      expect(component.someVariable).toBe("This");
    })
  });
});
```

Whenever `someMethod()` is getting called from the jest spec file, I want the service to be executed with some valid response object. But, Somehow it is always executing catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your mock you return the value, whereas a Promise is expected.

Try to wrap the value with `Promise.resolve`:

```js
  class mockServiceClass {
    test(): any {
      return Promise.resolve({ data: {}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {}, config: {} });
    }
  }
```